# Use count() as an integer in Spark Streaming

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am fairly new to Spark Streaming, and am doing a very simple program in Java that does the following:

I receive a series of numbers in string format (values5 variable), 5 every second,  convert them to Integers, and return the numbers again. This is the code I'm using:

```
JavaDStream<Integer> numbers = values5.map(new Function<String, Integer>() {
@Override
public Integer call(String s) throws Exception { 

 int c = Integer.parseInt(s);
 return c;
}
}
);
numbers.print();
```

(My RDD count, or values5.count(), returns 5 most of the time, as expected, since the batch duration is 1 second, and I'm getting 5 numbers per second).

The problem now, is that I only want to print 'numbers', if my values5.count() is 5 or more. That is, do something like this:

```
   JavaDStream<Integer> numbers = values5.map(new Function<String, Integer>() {
    @Override
    public Integer call(String s) throws Exception { 

 int c = Integer.parseInt(s);

if(values5.count()<5) {
     return 0;
}
else{
return c;
}
}
}
);
numbers.print();
```

But it doesn't work because numbers.count() is a JavaDstream and I can't compare it with a java.lang.Integer, or int.

What can I do? Thank you very much.

Comment: You should indent your code properly

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are looking for is discussed in [this mailing list post](https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/spark-user/201410.mbox/%3CCAMwrk0=YckuFxiZmSNa38p0fRgtAAKyQMbpvLGs1NKcrQOtVrQ@mail.gmail.com%3E)

You need to act on the represented RDD:

```
dstream.foreachRDD { rdd =>  val count = rdd.count() }
```

or

```
dstream.count().foreachRDD { rdd => val count = rdd.first() }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Justin, but the problem remains exactly the same, In the `filter` method I have to put the condition `value5.count()<5`, and I can't do it because value5.count() is not an integer

Comment: You're right, sorry about that. Updated my answer accordingly

Comment: Thank you, that definetely answers the question. However, it's still not working. The `foreachRDD` method is a void method,so if I put it in inside my `numbers` function (the one I wrote above) I can't use `count` for my if statement.
For example, I can't do `Integer cnt=dstream.foreachRDD(...)` and use cnt in my if statement, because the foreachRDD method returns a void.
I hope you understood my dillemma. Thank you again.